# Gradle task not ivoking class file

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

Following is the class file that I need to invoke through my task. The class file uses spock framework.

```
        Class RunTool extends Specification{
        blah blah...

        Properties collectData(){

               setup:
               blah blah...

              expect:
              blah blah...

              cleanup:
              blah blah...

              where:
              blah blah...
        }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunTool rt = new RunTool()
        rt.collectData()
    }

 }
```

The gradle task to run this class file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.package.RunTool'

task runBaselineFileTool(type:JavaExec, dependsOn:deploy) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.package.RunTool'
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.Package.RunTool.collectData() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at com.Package.RunTool.main(RunTool.groovy:72)
```

So if someone can please help me with this? My intent is to run the class file using gradle task.

Comment: Why should a test have a return value like `Properties`? Its return value should be void or just use `def`. And why do you run it manually instead of letting a JUnit/Spock runner do it? Maybe you should just stick to standards instead of re-inventing the unit testing wheel.

Comment: It looks like it probably has to do with your where block parameters. Have you tried actually listing them as parameters into your method?